# cant append array(state element) with setinterval() in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, setinterval

```
 const [timer,setTimer] = useState()
 const [number, setNumber] = useState()
 const [list, setlist] = useState([])

const numberChange = (number)=>{
    setNumber(number)
    if (!(list.find(item=>item===number))){
        setlist([...list,number])}
  }

  const randomNumber=()=> 1+Math.floor(Math.random()*90)

  const randNumberChange=()=>{
    let randNumber = randomNumber()
    if (list.find(item=>item===randNumber))
      randNumberChange()
      else
    numberChange(randNumber)
  }

  const startTimer = () => {
   setTimer(setInterval(()=>{
        randNumberChange()
   }, 5000))
}

const stopTimer=()=>{
    clearInterval(timer)
}
```

The list is always rendering only one item and not appending it.

When `randNumberChange` is called separately then the list gets appended but not with `setInterval`.

When `startTimer` funcion is executed is stopped with `stopTimer` and then started again it appends second item then stop and it repeats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `setlist([...list,number])}` to `setlist((prevState) => [...prevState, number])`. React set state is async in nature. So to get the correct list value from the state you would need to get the value from previous state. [Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

**Suggestion**: that instead of setting timer in state, you can start the interval in `useEffect`.

Also in `numberChange` function, you should get the `list` from previous state and then append the new number in that. This will make sure that the `list` value is updated before adding new number.

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Hello from "./Hello";
import "./style.css";
const Test = () => {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(null);
  const [list, setlist] = useState([]); 

  const numberChange = number => {
    setNumber(number);
    if (!list.find(item => item === number)) {
      setlist((prevState) => [...prevState, number]);// instead of directly using list value, get it from previous state
    }
  };

  const randomNumber = () => 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 90);

  const randNumberChange = () => {
    console.log("here");
    let randNumber = randomNumber();
    if (list.find(item => item === randNumber)) randNumberChange();
    else numberChange(randNumber);
  };

  const startTimer = () => {
     return setInterval(() => { randNumberChange(); }, 5000);
  }

  const stopTimer = (timer) => {
     clearInterval(timer)
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timer = startTimer();
    return ()=> stopTimer(timer);
  }, []);

  console.log(list);
  return <div>{number}</div>;
};
```

Comment: thank you this worked. i was changing the state directly. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // You don't need timer state, we'll clear this later
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    randNumberChange()
  },5000)
  return () => { // clear up
   clearInterval(interval)
  }
},[])
```

Answer (score 0):

use useEffect with setTimeout it is work as setInterval

```
useEffect(() => {
        
        setTimeout(() => setList([...list, newValue]), 2000)
}, [list])
```